# CP violation and arrow of time

Tags: reversibility, arrow-of-time, cp-violation

Does CP (and thus T) violation imply a definite arrow of time? How does it relate to the thermodynamic one? Does the microscopic irreversibility reflect itself to macroscopic level? If not why?

Comment: $T$-symmetry is a mathematical construct, it is not necessarily tied to how time actually behaves in the real world.

Comment: Note that T-violation has been explicitly observed in some B-meson decays at the LHC. Don't have a paper pointer right now, but this happened during the first run.